# numpy search array for multiple values, and returns their indices

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, search, numpy

How can I search for a small set of values in a numpy array (not sorted, and shouldn't be changed)?
It should return the indices of those values.

For example:

```
a = np.array(['d', 'v', 'h', 'r', 'm', 'a'])   # in general it will be large
query = np.array(['a', 'v', 'd'])

# Required:
idnx = someNumpyFunction(a, query)

print(indx)       # should be [5, 1, 0]
```

I'm a beginner in numpy and I couldn't find the proper way to do this task for multiple values at the same time (I know np.where(a=='d') can do it for a single value search).

Comment: If `query` is small, and there is no stringent need for optimisation, I would suggest a simple `for i in query: np.where(a==i)`. You have of course to handle edge cases: no matches, more than one match.

Comment: What do you want when a `query` element is not found in `a`?  What about repeats?

Comment: In my case query elements are unique and always exist. But even if there is a solution that may return -1 or outOfIndex for not found it is ok, but not raising exceptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A classic way of checking one array against another is adjust the shape and use '==':

```
In [250]: arr==query[:,None]
Out[250]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [251]: np.where(arr==query[:,None])
Out[251]: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([5, 1, 0]))
```

If an element `query` isn't found in `a`, its 'row' will be missing, e.g. `[0,2]` instead of `[0,1,2]`

```
In [261]: np.where(arr==np.array(['a','x','v'],dtype='S')[:,None])
Out[261]: (array([0, 2]), array([5, 1]))
```

For this small example, it is considerably faster than a list comprehension equivalent:

```
np.hstack([(arr==i).nonzero()[0] for i in query])
```

It's a little slower than the `searchsorted` solution.  (In that solution `i` is out of bounds if `query` element is not found).

---

Stefano suggested `fromiter`.  It saves some time compared to `hstack` of a list:

```
In [313]: timeit np.hstack([(arr==i).nonzero()[0] for i in query])10000 loops, best of 3: 49.5 us per loop

In [314]: timeit np.fromiter(((arr==i).nonzero()[0] for i in query), dtype=int, count=len(query))
10000 loops, best of 3: 35.3 us per loop
```

But if raises an error is an element is missing, or if there are multiple occurances.  `hstack` can handle variable length entries, `fromiter` cannot.

`np.flatnonzero(arr==i)` is slower than `().nonzero()[0]`, but I haven't looked into why.

Comment: +1 for the technique of transposing `query` and making use of broadcasting. Memory footprint is `n*k` bytes (size of `dtype=bool`), which for small `k` is comparable to `n` bytes for `(arr==i).nonzero()[0] for i in query`.

Comment: A more efficient way of writing the looping version is `np.fromiter((np.flatnonzero(arr==i) for i in query), dtype=int, count=len(query))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) on the sorted array, then revert the returned indices to the original array. For that you may use [`np.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html); as in:

```
>>> indx = a.argsort()  # indices that would sort the array
>>> i = np.searchsorted(a[indx], query)  # indices in the sorted array
>>> indx[i]  # indices with respect to the original array
array([5, 1, 0])
```

if `a` is of size `n` and `query` is of size `k`, this will be `O(n log n + k log n)` which would be faster than `O(n k)` for linear search if `log n < k`.

Comment: Actually in the case where 'n' is large and k is small, k is considered a constant, and this solution can reduced to 'O(n log n)', versus 'O(n)' for searching unsorted array. But we can say this solution will be generally suitable if I I'll do the search several times in a loop or something, in this case I can save the variable **indx** and don't have to sort again.

Comment: I would accept this solution if there is no other simple way to do it. In R and Matlab is it very easy just like indexing!!

Comment: The memory footprint of this solution is `n*(a.itemsize + indx.itemsize)`, since `a[indx]` is a copy and not a view. It is not clear to me under which hypothesis this would be faster than a simple loop over the elements of `query`

Comment: Yes, looping is a solution, but I hope there can be a simple one like in R and Matlab.